# terraform import: manage / import two remote objects in different regions with one resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I've imported my company's aws resources in us-west-2 to terraform, but we also have a few already existing identical resources in us-east-1. How would I import them to the same resource block that us-west-2 uses?

I'd prefer not to be able to switch between the regions based on which one I'm working on at that time, but I don't want nearly identical resource blocks just to support different regions.

Comment: I would probably use aliases for the same provider in different regions and then specify the alias in `provider` in the resource being imported: https://www.terraform.io/language/providers/configuration#selecting-alternate-provider-configurations.

Comment: This is litterally the problem Terragrunt solves. it may require some refactoring rearrangement of your terraform code but its worth it.

Comment: same issue after including provider alias
provider "aws" {
  alias   = "us-east-1"
  profile = "default"
  region  = "us-east-1"
}

provider "aws" {
  #alias   = "us-west-2"
  profile = "default"
  region  = "us-west-2"
}

resource "aws_vpc" "VPC" {
  providers = {    aws = aws.us-east-1  } ...


Error: Resource already managed by Terraform
│ Terraform is already managing a remote object for aws_vpc.VPC VPC. To import
│ to this address you must first remove the existing object from the state.


so I need terragrunt to solve this, or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: If you have the exact same resources in two regions, I would create a module for the common resources and then use the module once with the us-west-2 provider and once with the us-east-1 provider

Comment: @BrandonHorowitz Can you add the Terraform code you are trying to import? If you are setting the VPC logical name to the same value twice, import will not work anyway.

Comment: I'm not trying to import terraform "code", I'm trying to use `terraform import` to link an existing aws vpc from us-east-1 to aws_vpc.VPC, while aws_vpv.VPC is still linked to an existing aws vpc in us-west-2. 

i.e. using the command `terraform import aws_vpc.VPC <vpc_id>`